# Why do I continually have to run Get-SPUser for my Domain\User settings to show correctly?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am having trouble after our Domain move - some users periodically start showing up as `Domain\username` instead of their true profile name.

I found this thread on the subject and if I run the commandlette as per below, it fixes the issue.

Why though, do I have to run this every few days?

---

For multiple users in a site collection:

```
Get-SPUser –Web http://<sitecolurl>| Set-SPUser –SyncFromAD
```

Comment: Did you do a proper domain migration via ADMT?  Was this a domain or forest migration?  If it was just a domain migration, do you have a single UPSS connection setup to the forest, or more than one (should just be one)?  If you did a user migration (e.g. via ADMT), did you disable the source object once the account was migrated?

Answer (score 1):

When switching domain, you sometimes end up with users who don't get imported correct. You see them when they don't have first name and last name when they are logged in to SharePoint. They have `<domain>\<username>` visible instead.

You need to run a full sync, and then clean your profiles from these temporary users using the following script:

```
# Clean up accounts that is not imported correctly

$upsa = Get-SPServiceApplication | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -like "User Profile Service Application"}

# List all user accounts that is not imported correctly
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upsa -GetNonImportedObjects $true

# Remove user accounts not imported correctly 
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upsa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true

# Run a full User Profile Service Syncronisation, and make sure users
# end up in Profile database.
# If not, users who log in will create new NonImportedObject accounts
```

This might have to be repeated several times, especially if you're in a live environment where users login during the day. Eventually these orphan user profiles will disappear.
If you have a lot of users, the script will take a lot of time - so please be patient unless you get an error from PowerShell.

I've tried this in several different environments, and it does work. So in order to help others overcome this problem, I wrote this in my blog as well: [SharePoint 2010: Migrate Users to new Active Directory Environment](http://admin-sharepoint.blogspot.se/2013/02/migrate-users-to-new-active-directory.html).

Comment: how do I run that script? I don't know how to run a batch file from powershell, just single line commands...

Comment: @AprilD. You can place the content of the script in a text file and name it purgenonimportedusers.ps1 and save it in c:/script. Run Sharepoint management shell as admin and navigate to c:/script. Type ".\purgenonimportedusers.ps1" without quotation marks and hit enter. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the "NetBIOS" property is set properly in the UserProfile service application. We had a similar case where setting the enabling NETBIOS property for UPS resolved the issue. More details in the link below.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#NetBIOSProc